# 2D geometry outline shader

Tags: opengl-es, 2d, opengl-es-2.0, glsl, outline

I want to create a shader to outline 2D geometry. I'm using OpenGL ES2.0. I don't want to use a convolution filter, as the outline is not dependent on the texture, and it is too slow (I tried rendering the textured geometry to another texture, and then drawing that with the convolution shader). I've also tried doing 2 passes, the first being single colorded overscaled geometry to represent an oultine, and then normal drawing on top, but this results in different thicknesses or unaligned outlines. I've looking into how silhouette's in cel-shading are done but they are all calculated using normals and lights, which I don't use at all.

I'm using Box2D for physics, and have "destructable" objects with multiple fixtures. At any point an object can be broken down (fixtures deleted), and I want to the outline to follow the new outter counter.
I'm doing the drawing with a vertex buffer that matches the vertices of the fixtures, preset texture coordinates, and indices to draw triangles. When a fixture is removed, it's associated indices in the index buffer are set to 0, so no triangles are drawn there anymore.
The following image shows what this looks like for one object when it is fully intact.
The red points are the vertex positions (texturing isn't shown), the black lines are the fixtures, and the blue lines show the seperation of how the triangles are drawn. The gray outline is what I would like the outline to look like in any case.

[image: 1]

This image shows the same object with a few fixtures removed.

[image: 2]

Is this possible to do this in a vertex shader (or in combination with other simple methods)? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're able to do something about those awkward points that are slightly inset from the corners (eg, if you numbered the points in English-reading order, with the first being '1', point 6 would be one)...

If a point is interior then if you list all the polygon edges connected to it in clockwise order, each pair of edges in sequence will have a polygon in common. If any two edges don't have a polygon in common then it's an exterior point.

Starting from any exterior point you can then get the whole outline by first walking in any direction and subsequently along any edge that connects to an exterior point you haven't visited yet (or, alternatively, that isn't the edge you walked along just now).

Starting from an existing outline and removing some parts, you can obviously start from either exterior point that used to connect to another but no longer does and just walk from there until you get to the other.

You can't handle this stuff in a shader under ES because you don't get connectivity information.

---

I think the best you could do in a shader is to expand the geometry by pushing vertices outward along their surface normals. Supposing that your data structure is a list of rectangles, each described by, say, a centre, a width and a height, you could achieve the same thing by drawing each with the same centre but with a small amount added to the width and height.

To be completely general you'd need to store normals at vertices, but also to update them as geometry is removed. So there'd be some pushing of new information from the CPU but it'd be relatively limited.

Comment: Have you tried this method? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8499/Generating-Outlines-in-OpenGL

Comment: @MichaelIV I took that to be what the originating poster was referring to with "I've looking into how silhouette's in cel-shading are done but they are all calculated using normals and lights, which I don't use at all." — he's got 2d objects rather than 3d.